# Offered a job verbally but communication breaking down

Tags: email

I started a graduate job about 6 months ago and it really is not what I expected or want. So I approached a company I worked for on a placement one summer and asked if they had any vacancies. I met up with my old manager, he discussed 4 possible options they had for me and we left on a gentlemans agreement that I'd take up one of the roles.

I was told to expect it to take a month for a contract to be set up, and we are almost at that point now.

I emailed after a couple of weeks to check how things were going and was told to expect something at the start of last week, after not hearing anything I emailed again a couple of days ago and have not had a reply, which is odd because I know he would normally reply fairly quickly, I also know he's been in the office.

Naturally I'm quite concerned, this job is a perfect fit for me, could anyone advise how to best approach the situation now?

How long is the correct amount of time now to wait before sending another email?

I am wanting to move jobs sooner rather than later, so I'm looking into other vacancies, but if I do apply for other vacancies it's a small city and the tech companies talk, so it would get back to my old manager as they are on my CV and I don't want him to think I'm not wanting the job with him as they are my first choice.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like he might have liked to hire you, but that on further thought, or on the reaction of some other people in the office, those plans have been put on hold.

*Most likely* he doesn't want to have to tell you "sorry, deal's off", so he's not getting back to you.

It's time to move on. If they end up getting back to you, great. But I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: That's exactly how I'm reading the situation. I guess I'll email again in a weeks time then leave it alone and in the meantime apply to other vacancies.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than continuing to send e-mail, if you are really set on this job, I would pick up the telephone and call him.  Perhaps there is a situation that has delayed/canceled the opening that would be easier to explain verbally than in writing.

I think I would assume it is time to start looking elsewhere.  In general, it's probably best to not count on a job until you have an offer in writing.  I've had several instances where I got through the interview process and then the position was closed due to budget changes or it was filled internally.